# AMCL claims no data is being published even though there is (including tf data)

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to get navigation to run on my robot. To do this I am currently trying to get AMCL to work on ROS kinetic (ubuntu 16.04 Xenial).

My setup consists of 3 machines (of which 2 are relevant). I have:

- My server: which is running a roscore, amcl, robot control software etc
- A raspberry Pi 3 with a RPLidar A3 connected running the lidar ros pacakge ''
- A virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer which is used to run GUI's Rviz, rqt_tf_tree, ...

Data can be published and received from all machines so I think this is working (I set the ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP variables and I edited the /etc/hosts file)

The lidar works and publishes data correctly (confirmed in Rviz and through rostopic echo).
[image: image description]

However AMCL gives the following error every 15 seconds:

```
[ WARN] [1551364654.979541753]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1551364654.979506 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /rplidar topic.
```

I do not get the error when using a different laserscan (the one from the robot instead of the RPLidar for instance).
I have tried letting the lidar publish to the base_footprint frame directly as well as to a separate 'laser' fixed frame for which I then run:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.0 base_footprint laser  50
```

Running roswtf on the server machine does not yield anything useful (only some unconnected topics).
Running it on the Raspberry does however:

```
WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
 * receiving transform from [/naoqi_driver_node] that differed from ROS time by 86.070399184s
 * receiving transform from [/static_transform_publisher_1551361858545724424] that differed from ROS time by 86.129054226s
```

The same info is given when i run roswtf from the virtual box machine.

A screenshot of rqt_tf_tree is below:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

And output of `rosrun tf tf_echo base_footprint laser`:

```
At time 1551365866.147
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 1551365866.898
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 1551365867.899
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
```

I am totally at a loss so any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards
Christof

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317043/amcl-claims-no-data-is-being-published-even-though-there-is-(including-tf-data)/) by [cmahieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40262/cmahieu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Receiving transform from [..] that differed from ROS time by 86.129054226s

With "multiple machines" and issues with TF / subscribers the first thing to check would be time synchronisation across all machines involved. Can you confirm you've done that?

---

Edit:

> I had no idea synchronization was something to take into account.

It is pretty logical though, if you think about it: how would we be able to temporally correlate sensor data (or more generally: publications) coming from different machines without a common/shared/synchronised clock?

> I quickly forced synchronisation by taking the desyncrhonized data and publishing it to a new topic without the old time info and this works (as a temp solution).

You probably already figured it out, but republishing like that is certainly not a real solution.

Take a look at [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup - Timing issues, TF complaining about extrapolation into the future?](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Timing_issues.2C_TF_complaining_about_extrapolation_into_the_future.3F) for a solution.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmahieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40262/cmahieu/) on 2019-02-28**:
Hi

I had no idea synchronization was something to take into account. I quickly forced synchronisation by taking the desyncrhonized data and publishing it to a new topic without the old time info and this works (as a temp solution). Thank you! I would not have been able to solve this without you!